# wrapping tuple members in other templated types

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I'd like to be able to declare a class with a template pack, such that the class itself will have a member variable tuple that wraps each of the template pack members in a container type of some sort.  A basic goal would look like:

```
template <typename Types...>
class VectorOfMembers 
{
public:
    // Member tuple where each element is expanded in a container
    std::tuple<std::vector<Type[1]>, std::vector<Type[2]>, std::vector<TypeN...>>
};
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this with any templated object as the wrapping type too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you almost had it:

```
template <typename... Types>
class VectorOfMembers
{
public:
    // Member tuple where each element is expanded in a container
    std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...> tuple;
};
```